# Using Qt to create the OS X Yosemite Translucency effect

Tags: macos, qt, translucency

We're trying to make a QMainWindow with the Mac OSX Yosemite translucency effect. We're using PyQt, but the problem is a Qt issue. With what we've tried so far, it's always either fully transparent or fully opaque (like a normal window). If we turn on Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, the window background becomes 100% completely transparent. 

Additionally, the QGraphicsView we're displaying on it then leaves trails behind when you scroll. The mouse input also "passes through" the transparent parts - clicking on a transparent portion of the graphics view will register as a click on the window behind it. Setting a stylesheet with any custom background color then has no effect. If we turn it off, the window remains opaque. Then we can change the background color using a style sheet, but it's still opaque. 
Turing WA_FramelessWindowHint on and off doesn't seem to fix anything, either. Nor does setAutoFillBackground(). Do you know how to make a window with the Yosemite translucency effect?

Here's a sample Python program to test this: -

```
# Attempt at Mac OSX Translucency (example code)

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
Qt = QtCore.Qt

class ExampleMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.testWidget = QtWidgets.QLabel('Test label, which should be transparent')

        # Make sure the testWidget is transparent
        self.testWidget.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')
        self.testWidget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.testWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.setStyleSheet('background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)')
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint) # Doesn't seem to help

        self.setCentralWidget(self.testWidget)

def main():
    global app, exWindow
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    exWindow = ExampleMainWindow()
    exWindow.show()
    exitcodesys = app.exec_()
    app.deleteLater()
    sys.exit(exitcodesys)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Code is sometimes worth of thousand words.

Comment: I don't understand how to embed the code into the post, so here it is in a pastie:
https://bpaste.net/show/b0fbe94e90ce

Comment: Some tips on formatting code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: So the person helping me with this project made a sample Python program to test this. This is the code: https://bpaste.net/show/8c1abf7c0dfc

This is the output: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ger3m15humuyymx/Screenshot%202014-12-07%2012.32.39.png?dl=0

This is an example of the type of code we're trying to work with - only we want it to have the 'frosted glass' look from Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet isn't valid. Qt's rgba expects an integer in range 0-255 or a percentage for the values only. So use 80% instead of 0.8. Along with WA_TranslucentBackground that should get you going.

And please post your code in the question, as your pastes expire in a few days and this question will then be unusable.

Here is code that is working for me; I see my other applications' windows underneath. It's C++. I'm using Qt4 rather than 5; perhaps this matters.

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

class MyMain : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyMain(QWidget* parent = 0);

};

MyMain::MyMain(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    setStyleSheet("background: rgba(0,0,0,80%);");

    QLabel* foo = new QLabel();
    foo->setText("hello");
    foo->setStyleSheet("color: white;");
    setCentralWidget(foo);
}

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyMain m;
    m.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: If I set it to a percentage (say, '80%') without setting WA_TranslucentBackground to True, it only has a greyscale (no seeing through to windows underneath) - but if I set WA_TranslucentBackground to True, it is completely transparent and I can even click windows under it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfbj5cabzl0gwb7/Screenshot%202014-12-07%2017.29.18.png?dl=0<br>
Is there a known way to also give it the 'frosted glass' look instead of a simple translucency?

Comment: I tried running this today, and it gave the error that QMainWindow could not be found. Could you help me with that? Additionally, could you take a screenshot of your output so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: If you use Qt5, you would need QT += QtWidgets in the project file. Here's my screenshot: http://i57.tinypic.com/2rystjk.png

Comment: The SS you sent looks good - however, it doesn't appear to have the frosted-glass look (although it doesn't look like you're using Yosemite). Would that code give the frosted-glass look on Yosemite, do you know?

Comment: Here's a screenshot from Yosemite - http://i58.tinypic.com/2lvk3vd.jpg . No it doesn't have the look you want; I expect you'd need to put a textured background in your own application rather than the plain rgba(0,0,0,80%).